Is it posible to deserialize JSON to a generics object in C# and have the property name be dynamic?
Updated: Either of the two comments at time of update or the accepted answer are functional solutions, however at the scale being applied introduce more risk and complexity than they would save. Therefore, I’ve opted to just have a multitude of classes in a separate file with each response written out separately.
I would be happy to use either of NewtonSoft or System.Text.Json deserializers.
I'll have many different responses coming from an API, and would prefer not to write up seperate response objects for each.
For example, every response has a message property and a status code property, then it's actual data.
So, what I'd like to have is
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public string StatusCode{ get; set; }
    public string Message{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<T> Data { get; set; }
}

The issue is that, while I can correctly set 'T', I can't have the deserialization map to it, because it expects the property to be "Users" or "Purchases" etc., not "data".
I am aware I can set JsonProperty[] decorator, but the issue is this isn't dynamic with T.
If there's technically a way but it's no cleaner than just creating separate response objects for each I'm happy to continue to write up separate objects; but would be interested in a better solution I haven't found if one exist.

Define a custom contract-resolver.

may be JsonExtensionData is way to go!

Whenever you hit something like this that's a little bit off the beaten path, the general solution is to write a JsonConverter implementation to handle it yourself. Yes, you can do all sorts of tricky things with wrapper classes and so on. I do a lot of that myself... but it's not very generic.
The basic concepts are outlined in "How to write custom converters for JSON serialization. Of the two patterns (basic and factory), the factory pattern lets you handle generic types.
Once you've defined the factory type you use the JsonConverter attribute to signal the json serializer/deserializer that you want this specific converter (or factory in this case) to be used with your type:
public class ApiResponseConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    // refer to the fiddle for details
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(ApiResponseConverterFactory))]
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public string StatusCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public T? Data { get; set; }

    // This is just a convenience in case you want to re-serialize.
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string? DataPropName { get; set; }
}

As to the actual code... here's a fiddle. I've put together a simple converter factory that does... the basics.
